# It only gives one string as the output

Tags: java, arrays, string, substring, startswith

If I enter 3 objects

```
aakash
12323
aakshit
24r352
rahul
12323
```

If i give this as a input and enter search string as 'aa' then it gives only first string that matches the search ouput will be

```
aakash
12323
```

why not aakshit also

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
public class DA_2_searching {
    String name,phone_number;
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    DA_2_searching()
    {
        System.out.print("Enter the Details");
        name=s.nextLine();
        phone_number= s.nextLine();
    }
    void search()
    {
       String search;
       search=s.nextLine();
       if(name.startsWith(search))
       {
           System.out.println(name);
           System.out.println(phone_number);

       }
    }
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int n;
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        n= s.nextInt();
        DA_2_searching obj[]= new DA_2_searching[n];

        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            obj[i]= new DA_2_searching();
        }
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            obj[i].search();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try debugging your program?

Comment: each call to `search` is using a fresh input from the Scanner - is that really what you want?

Comment: obj[i].search(); this is problem. It will always search on object at index i. But not on all objects

Answer (score 1):

The reason for your problem is, that you only *search* for one object at a time. Your for loop that calls the `search()` function only compares one *object* to a *search input* at a time.

In the `for` *loop*, you are only calling the *search function* for one `DA_2_searching` object (the one with index `i - obj[i]`). But you want to search in every `DA_2_searching` object you created, that means you have to rework the `search()` function so that it gets all `DA_2_searching` objects and compares them to the *search*-String.

Here's my solution:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class DA_2_searching {

private String name, phone_number;
private static DA_2_searching[] allPersons;
private static Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

public DA_2_searching() {
    System.out.println("Enter the Details: ");
    System.out.print("Name: ");
    this.name = s.next();
    System.out.print("Phone-Number: ");
    this.phone_number = s.next();
    System.out.println("\nNext: ");
}

public static void search() {
    System.out.println("Type a word to search for: ");
    String toSearch = s.next();     
    for(DA_2_searching person : allPersons) {
        if(person.name.contains(toSearch)) { //contains is better for searching.
            System.out.println("Result: " + person.name + " | " + person.phone_number);
        }
    }
    System.out.println("\n");
    if(!toSearch.equals("exit")) {
        search();
    }

}
public static void main(String args[]) {
    System.out.print("Amount of Entries: ");
    int n = s.nextInt();
    System.out.println("");
    allPersons = new DA_2_searching[n];
    //Creating Persons
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        allPersons[i] = new DA_2_searching();
    }
    //initializing search
    search();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

In your current code you search for a String in every iteration. You read in a String and check if this String equals Array[0] then you print it. Then you read in a String again and check if it is equal to Array[1]... and so on. What you want is a search in the whole Array. 
**A simple solution would be to read in the String before the 2nd loop and pass the 
string into search();**

```
void search(String search) {

    if (name.startsWith(search)) {
        System.out.println(name);
        System.out.println(phone_number);

    }
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    int n;
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    n = s.nextInt();
    DA_2_searching obj[] = new DA_2_searching[n];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        obj[i] = new DA_2_searching();
    }
    String search = new String();
    search = s.nextLine();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        obj[i].search(search);
    }
}
```